# Getting 0% coverage report using jacoco-gwt-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, gwt, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to get coverage report of GWTTestCases using jacoco-gwt-maven-plugin.

I followed the below link:
https://github.com/errai/jacoco-gwt-maven-plugin

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512m</extraJvmArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.4.201202141554</version>
            <configuration>
                <snapshotDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</snapshotDirectory>
                <propertyName>jacocoArgs</propertyName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${jacocoArgs}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>      
</build>
```

When I run the Project using commands as,
mvn clean
mvn install
Inside target folder I can see,
site Directory --> jacoco Directory --> index.html file gets created.

When I open index.html, code coverage is 0%.
What I am doing wrong, Please help.

I got some help from link below, but still struggling to get complete report
[How do I setup coverage with GWT, maven, jacoco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638478/how-do-i-setup-coverage-with-gwt-maven-jacoco)

In target\test-classes folder I can see only GwtTestCovergeSample.class file from test package, does client and server folder class files should also be present here?